# srtotime(), date(), and ACF fuunction working MOST of the time...what's going wrong?

Tags: php, wordpress, date, advanced-custom-fields, strtotime

I am using the function below to return the status of a current show for my theatre company.  I am then using these status changes to style things differently...IE, making images faded to indicate past shows etc.  This is working MOST of the time.  But for some reason on the last day the show is running, the function is returning 'past' when, according to my logic, it should return 'playing'.  This function works for every day EXCEPT the last / closing day of the shows. Help is much appreciated in finding my logic flaw :))

```
// Get the STATUS of a show to determine where it is at in the show lifecycle
// @return      string      lower case status of a show
// @returns tba, playing, rehearsing, past, future
// @uses ACF, date(), and strtotime()
// @author Christopher Hahn
// @since 1.1
// ==================================================================

if ( ! function_exists( 'wolf_get_show_status' ) ){

function wolf_get_show_status(){



    // Make sure date and time field are populated with data
    if( get_field( 'show_start_date' ) && get_field( 'show_end_date' ) ){

        // Get today's Date
        $today = date("Ymd");

        // Get Raw Dates from ACF values
        $show_start_date = get_field( 'show_start_date', false, false);
        $show_end_date = get_field( 'show_end_date', false, false);

        //Get the approproate timestamps from the dates
        // @note rehearsal_start_ts will be used to determine if the show is in rehearsal
        // by taking the starting date of the show, and subtracting one month
        // =============================================================
        $rehearsals_start_ts = strtotime( $show_start_date .'-1month' );
        $show_start_ts = strtotime( $show_start_date );
        $show_end_ts = strtotime( $show_end_date );
        $today_ts = strtotime( $today );

         // Check that show date is between start & end date, meaning it is currently in it's run
         if ( ($today_ts >= $show_start_ts) && ( $today_ts <= $show_end_ts)){

             $show_status = 'playing';

         }

         // Check to see if the show is one month out from the start date, if it is, the show is in rehearsal
          elseif (($today_ts > $rehearsals_start_ts) && ( $today_ts < $show_start_ts )){

             $show_status = 'rehearsing';

         }

         // Check to see of the show is past it's end date
         elseif ( $today_ts > $show_end_ts ){

             $show_status = 'past';

         }


         // Check to see if the show is a future show but not yet in rehearsal
          elseif (( $today_ts < $show_start_ts) && $show_status != 'rehearsing' ){

             $show_status = 'future';

         } else{


            // Set a default of TBA when start and end dates are not selected
            $show_status = 'tba';

         }

    }

     return $show_status;

}
```

}

Comment: Which timezone you have set? have you checked your current timezone with timezone set in your code or of your server?

Comment: Indeed...current time sone is set to EST